# How to create AppId for BurntToast?

Tags: powershell, notifications, windows-10, toast

Fist of all, BurntToast is a Powershell module which is used for creating toast notifications.

I can create notifications with buttons like this:

[image: Click this link in order to see the notification.]

I want to change "Windows PowerShell" text. In order to do this, `"AppId"` variable which is exist in `config.json` should be changed.

Default contents of `config.json` file:

```
{
    "AppId":  "{1AC14E77-02E7-4E5D-B744-2EB1AE5198B7}\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "AppLogo":  "\\Images\\BurntToast.png"
}
```

But, when I change this variable, I get this error:

[image: Click this link in order to see the error.]

So, what should I do?

Comment: The warning quite literally tells you what to do: "please run `New-BTAppId`"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have fixed my problem myself.

In order to fix this issue, the application should be packed into a installation program and the application should be installed to end user's computer.

Because Windows only assigns AppIds to installed apps, not portable apps.

By the way, system apps (such as osk.exe, cmd.exe, powershell.exe etc.) have AppIds even they have not a installer software.